# Font - math mode in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, latex

I used this for font:

```
\usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{fdsymbol}"

params = {'text.usetex' : True,
          'font.size' : 20,
          'font.family' : 'lcmodern',
          }
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

and this for text - LaTeX math mode

```
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$T$ [s]')
```

How to set a font of math mode to something like Arial, Trebuchet...?

[image]

After advice:

[image]

It does not work for ticks.

I tried:

```
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r"\usepackage{bm} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{fdsymbol} \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}" 

params = {'text.usetex' : True,
          'font.size' : 20,
          }
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

and

```
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r"\usepackage{bm} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{fdsymbol} \usepackage{sansmath} \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}" 

params = {'text.usetex' : True,
          'font.size' : 20,
          }
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

Comment: Does it have to be arial or would a sans serif font be enough?

Comment: Yes, a sans-serif would be fine.

Comment: Try with the `\usepackage{sansmath}` package

Comment: Thank you. How to force it to work also for ticks? I added the result to my question.

Comment: Maybe you can try `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`

Comment: It does not work. Did you mean that I added to my question?